# Java, operation on double - after decimal point

Tags: java, android

I have double in format xx,yy (for example 21,69).

I don't know how to make condition:

```
if (yy > 60) {
 yy = yy - 60
 xx = xx + 1
}
```

Do you have any idea how to do that in Java ?

Comment: What specifically is your issue? Is it using the `if` statement or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = (int)xx,yy;
double zz = xx,yy-n;

if(zz > 60) {
    zz = zz - 60;
    n++;
}

double xx, yy = n + zz;
```

input 21.69
output=22.09

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
double i = 21.69;

double yy = (i - ((int)i))*100;
int xx = (int)i;

if (yy > 60) {
    yy = yy - 60;
    xx = xx + 1;
}

double result = xx + (yy/100);
System.out.println(result);
```

which prints: 22.09